# Need boolean value isTouched()

Tags: java, android

I need to detect WHEN the screen is touched. The onTouchEvent method only detects when the finger is moving. I need method which returns boolean value true, when the finger touches screen and returns false, when its not.

Comment: i hope on touch event detects a touch event like this eg public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {}if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {} and action move like the above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very basic implementation of the onTouch method that modifies a boolean value to know if a the screen is touched. You may need to tweak it to suit your specific needs (and maybe handle multi touch)

```
private boolean mIsScreenTouched;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        mIsScreenTouched = true; 
        break; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL :    
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        mIsScreenTouched = false; 
        break; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I always thought that the ACTION.UP and ACTION.DOWN detects when the finger is moved UP or DOWN :)

Comment: Actuaaly they mean the first and last contact. Also if it was the case, you would have somewhere an ACTION_LEFT and ACTION_RIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
    if(btn.onTouchEvent(e)){
        return btn.onTouchEvent(e);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```